# Applying jquery-ui droppable on nested lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I am trying to use jquery droppable on a nested list, applying a change to the background colour of the li on hover.  The problem is that it is only applying to the first item in a list.  The alert is still alerting the text within the list item though.  Any ideas why this would be happening?

```
  $("#mailbox li").droppable({
   greedy: true,
   hoverClass: 'mailbox-hover',
   drop: function(event, ui) {
    alert($(this).text());
   }
  });
```

[**Edit**]
On some testing, the alert is working right, the hover class is being applied (according to fireBug) but it will only change the text-color when I hover over the first element.

```
<ul id="mailbox" class="filetree">
  <li>
    <span class="folder">imap@gazler.com
    </span>
    <ul>
      <li id="0-INBOX">
        <span class="folder">
        </span>
        <a href="#" onclick="changeFolder('0', 'INBOX', 'INBOX');" name="INBOX">INBOX
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li id="0-INBOX-Drafts">
            <span class="file">
            </span>
            <a href="#" onclick="changeFolder('0', 'INBOX.Drafts', 'Drafts');" name="INBOX.Drafts">Drafts
            </a>
          <li id="0-INBOX-Sent">
            <span class="file">
            </span>
            <a href="#" onclick="changeFolder('0', 'INBOX.Sent', 'Sent');" name="INBOX.Sent">Sent
            </a>
          <li id="0-INBOX-Trash">
            <span class="folder">
            </span>
            <a href="#" onclick="changeFolder('0', 'INBOX.Trash', 'Trash');" name="INBOX.Trash">Trash
            </a>
            <ul>
              <li id="0-INBOX-Trash-New">
                <span class="file">
                </span>
                <a href="#" onclick="changeFolder('0', 'INBOX.Trash.New', 'New');" name="INBOX.Trash.New">New
                </a>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

[**css is comments**] - Also, possibly related, possibly a css error, it won't let me set the background-color of the li on hover, only font color.

```
.mailbox-hover
{
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.mailbox-dropped
{
    color: #ffff00;
}
```

[**solved**] - And finally, it won't let me alert ($(this).id) even though the all the list items have an id attached.

Comment: For the ID alert use `alert($(this).attr("id"));`

Comment: If you suspect a css error, post your css.

Comment: .mailbox-hover
{
 background-color: #0000ff;
}

Comment: Can you post a chunk of html you're running this against?  It would help tremendously in answering.

Comment: Try removing the 0- on the start of the IDs...this is invalid HTML and may be causing problems.  I'll test the other here and update

Comment: Hi, I am afraid that isn't the issue.  Cheers for the tip though.

Comment: Try this for CSS:  `#mailbox li { background-color: #ffffff; } #mailbox li.mailbox-hover { background-color: #0000ff;} .mailbox-dropped { color: #ffff00; }`  Does that cure what you're problem is?  I'm not entirely sure what's not working for you....change the `#ffffff` to your BG color of course. - Moving this into an answer for more scratch room while we figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for alert:

```
alert($(this).attr("id"));
```

This for CSS:

```
#mailbox li { background-color: #ffffff; } 
#mailbox li.mailbox-hover { background-color: #0000ff;} 
.mailbox-dropped { color: #ffff00; }
```

I'll continue to update this answer while we work through...easier formatting here.

Comment: That won't be necessary, it is now fixed.  :)  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Gazler Good to hear, hope it gives you no more trouble.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to nesting dropped items:

```
// Make the drop_area div droppable
$("#drop_area").droppable({
 accept: "#temp_item",
 drop: function(event,ui){

  // Get the id of the item that was just dropped
  var id = ui.draggable.attr('id');

  // Clone the item and append it to the drop area
  $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());

  // Remove the ability to drag the current item around
  $('#temp_region').removeClass("dragg");
  $('#temp_region').removeClass("ui-draggable");

  // Create a new name for the dropped item
  var $new_name = rnd();
  $('#' + id).attr('id', $new_name);

  // Remove the dropped item's CSS position directives
  $('#' + $new_name).css('top', '');
  $('#' + $new_name).css('left', '');

  // Make the newly renamed item droppable so that nesting can take place
  $('#' + $new_name).droppable({
   accept: '*',
   drop: function(e,ui){
    if ( e.clientY < $(this).closest("div").position().top + $(this).closest("div").height() )
    {
     // Determine what is being dropped and onto what
     var dropped_item = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
     var dropped_on = $(this).attr('id');

     // Get the HTML of each item
     var dropped_html = $('#' + dropped_item).html();
     var dropped_on_html = $('#' + dropped_on).html();

     // Remove the dropped item from the DOM
     $('#' + dropped_item).remove();

     // Append the dropped item into the item it was just dropped on
     $('#' + dropped_on).append(ui.draggable);

     // Remove the dropped item's CSS position directives
     $('#' + dropped_item).css('top', '');
     $('#' + dropped_item).css('left', '');

     // Let the user move the dropped item
     $('#' + dropped_item).draggable();
    }
   }
  });

  // Force the dropped item to only move around in the container
  $('#' + $new_name).draggable({containment: '#drop_area'});

  // All the user to snap items to each other for usability sake
  $('#' + $new_name).draggable({
   snap: true,
   stop: function(event, ui){
   }
  });
 }
});
```